# Serialize a string using reduce() in python

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I am trying to learn the functional programming way of doing things in python. I am trying to serialize a list of strings in python using the following code

```
S = ["geeks", "are", "awesome"]
reduce(lambda x, y: (str(len(x)) + '~' + x) + (str(len(y)) +  '~' + y), S)
```

I am expecting:

```
5~geeks3~are7~awesome
```

But I am seeing:

```
12~5~geeks3~are7~awesome
```

Can someone point out why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `initializer` parameter - an empty string to the `reduce()` function. It will be the first argument passed to the `lambda` function before the values from the list.

```
from functools import reduce

S = ["geeks", "are", "awesome"]

reduce(lambda x, y: x + f'{len(y)}~{y}', S, '')
# 5~geeks3~are7~awesome
```

Equivalent to:

```
((('' + '5~geeks') + '3~are') + '7~awesome')
# 5~geeks3~are7~awesome
```

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` function on each current iteration relies on previous item/calculation (the nature of all ***reduce*** routines), that's why you got `12` at the start of the resulting string: on the 1st pass the item was `5~geeks3~are` with length `12` and that was used/prepended on next iteration.

Instead, you can go with simple *consecutive* approach:

```
lst = ["geeks", "are", "awesome"]
res = ''.join('{}~{}'.format(str(len(s)), s) for s in lst)
print(res)    # 5~geeks3~are7~awesome
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reduce` function is for aggregation. What you're trying to do is mapping instead.

You can use the `map` function for the purpose:

```
''.join(map(lambda x: str(len(x)) + '~' + x, S))
```

This returns:

```
5~geeks3~are7~awesome
```

Answer (score 1):

- here is the solution for `pyton3.7+` using `fstring`.

```py
>>> S = ["geeks", "are", "awesome"]
>>> ''.join(f'{len(s)}~{s}' for s in S)
'5~geeks3~are7~awesome'
```